# Can not register new user via php form

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a simple registration with php & mysql and everything looks great but I don't know why nothing inserts into database & an error occure.
Here's my full code:

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['agreement'])=="checked"){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
        $select = $_POST['slct1'];

        if(!empty($username)){
            if(strlen($username)>5){
                $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username='$username'"); 
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
                    echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; The username that you have entered has been already registered!</code></p></br>";
                }else{
                    if(!empty($email)){
                        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $query2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE email='$email'"); 
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($query2) > 0){
                                echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; The email that you have entered has been already added!</code></p></br>";
                            }else{
                                if(!empty($password)){
                                    if (strlen($password)>10){
                                        if ($password==$password2){
                                            $register = "INSERT INTO admins username='$username',email='$email',gender='$gender',password='$password',adminlevel='$select'";
                                            $register = mysqli_query($con, $register);
                                            if ($register){
                                                echo "<p class='success'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; The admin registered successfully. He/she can now login to sitebook...</code></p></br>";
                                            }else{
                                                echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; An error occured. Try again later!</code></p></br>";
                                            }
                                        }else{
                                            echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; Passwords do not match. Try again please!</code></p></br>";
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; The password should be more than 10 characters!</code></p></br>";
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; Don't forget to fill password field!</code></p></br>";
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; The email you have entered is not a valid one!</code></p></br>";
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; Don't forget to fill email field!</code></p></br>";
                    }
                }
            }else{      
                echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; Your username must be more than 5 characters!</code></p></br>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; Don't forget to fill username field!</code></p></br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<p class='error'><code>&nbsp;&nbsp; You need to check the agreement in order to continue!</code></p></br>";
    }
}
?>
<!-- START OF DEFAULT WIZARD -->
                <h4 class="subtitle2">Fill The Form Completely</h4>
                    <form class="stdform" method="POST" action="">
                    <div id="wizard" class="wizard">
                        <br />
                        <ul class="hormenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#wiz1step1">
                                    <span class="h2">Step 1</span>
                                    <span class="label">Basic Information</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#wiz1step2">
                                    <span class="h2">Step 2</span>
                                    <span class="label">Account Information</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#wiz1step3">
                                    <span class="h2">Step 3</span>
                                    <span class="label">Terms of Agreement</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div id="wiz1step1" class="formwiz" >
                            <h4 class="widgettitle">Step 1: Basic Information</h4>

                                <p >
                                    <div class="par">
                                        <label style="text-align:left;">Username</label>
                                        <div class="input-prepend">
                                            <span class="add-on">@</span>
                                            <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="prependedInput" class="span2" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <label style="text-align:left;">Email</label>
                                    <span class="field">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input-xxlarge" required/>
                                    </span>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <label style="text-align:left;">Gender</label>
                                    <span class="field">
                                        <select name="gender" id="selection" class="uniformselect">
                                            <option value="1">Male</option>
                                            <option value="2">Female</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </span>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <label style="text-align:left;">Temorary Password</label>
                                    <span class="field">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-xxlarge" required/>
                                    </span>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <label style="text-align:left;">Confirm Password</label>
                                    <span class="field">
                                        <input type="password" name="password2" id="password" class="input-xxlarge" required/>
                                    </span>
                                </p>



                        </div><!--#wiz1step1-->

                        <div id="wiz1step2" class="formwiz">
                            <h4 class="widgettitle">Step 2: Account Information</h4>

                                <p>
                                    <label style="text-align:left;">Which Kind Of These Types Your Admin Is:</label>
                                    <span class="field">
                                    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')" class="uniformselect" required>
                                      <option value=""></option>
                                      <option value="Adminstrator">Adminstrator</option>
                                      <option value="ContentC">Content Creator</option>
                                      <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </span>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                <label style="text-align:left;">Then Your Admin Can Be Able To:</label>
                                <span class="field">
                                <select style="max-width:90%;" disabled="disabled" id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
                                </span>
                                </p>

                        </div><!--#wiz1step2-->

                        <div id="wiz1step3">
                            <h4 class="widgettitle">Step 3: Careful</h4>
                            <div class="par terms" style="padding: 0 20px;font-size:17px;">
                                <p>You can change the admin type later on in <i>all admins</i> section settings.</p>
                                <p><strong>Sitebook</strong> is not responsible for what your admins post on the site. This is on your risk so please take care of your site yourself! </p>
                                <p>Thanks...</p>
                                <p><input name="agreement" value="checked" type="checkbox"  /> I agree with this</p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--#wiz1step3-->

                    </div><!--#wizard-->
                    <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset Button</button>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Admin</button>
                    </form>
                    <!-- END OF DEFAULT WIZARD -->
```

When I try to submit the form with correct information ,no php errors comes up and only one error message which is `An error occured. Try again later!` appears (that I wrote in line 31)

There might a problem that data can not be inserted but I don't whats that!

This is also my **admin** table instruction:

```
username    varchar(16)
email   varchar(255)
password    varchar(255)
gender  varchar(11)
adminlevel  varchar(11)
```

Please if you how to solve this problem ,please let me know...

**Note**: I skipped writing how I connect my database cause it's already alright!

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and instead of a fixed (useless) "a problem occured" messages, have the DB **TELL** you why the queries failed: `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: 12 levels of nested `if` statements is a pain to debug. Try to reduce how many levels there are, and it'll be easier to debug your code.

Comment: you're using UPDATE/SET syntax for your INSERT. having checked for errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have signaled the error

Answer (score 1):

1) you need to use prepared statements or otherwise secure your user input before inserting it.

2) the reason for the error is because your SQL is not valid. Change it to the following:

```
"INSERT INTO admins (username,email,gender,password,adminlevel) VALUES ('$username','$email','$gender','$password','$select')";
```

Comment: and what exactly did you do/change here? this, for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your INSERT query

```
INSERT INTO admins username='$username',email='$email',gender='$gender',password='$password',adminlevel='$select'";
```

Try

```
INSERT INTO admins (username, email, gender, password, adminlevel) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$gender', '$password', '$select');
```

If you are developing this in a private, secure development environment, you can debug your MySQL errors using something along the lines of:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO admins (username, email, gender, password, adminlevel) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$gender', '$password', '$select')"))
{
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

See [MySQL `INSERT` Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) for more information about the syntax of INSERT statements and [PHP `mysqli_error()` Function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) for more information on the above.

On an unrelated note, it is a very dangerous practice to write unprepared statements like the SELECT and INSERT queries above. They are very open to [SQL injection exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementations). I would advise looking into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to  make sure that your site isn't hacked!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO admins SET username='$username',email='$email',gender='$gender',password='$password',adminlevel='$select'
```

Use `SET`. Then the query will be fine.

Comment: The query works with `VALUES` as well. Just different syntax. IMHO, `VALUES` is less obstrusive and easier to read then `SET`.

Comment: Yes you are 100% right. I never used "INSERT INTO" with SET. Here just pointed what was missing in his statement. Thanks.... By the way others are replying, it sounds using INSERT INTO in that way is wrong!!!!